# How to add framework based on configuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, frameworks

i have a framework which i want to add to add only in debug mode but not in release mode. I saw few post on the same where they ask to add -framework myframework in other linker flag . I tried this solution and also added the framework path based on configuration. My app build fine but it crashes on launch with message library not loaded @rpath ... not found. Can anyone please help me and tell me the proper way to add framework to debug configuration only . Thanks !!!

Comment: More context is needed to be able to answer, but here's a good starting point to understand how @rpath and friends work:
https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html
Let us know what's the "install name" for the  library you're linking in Debug and where are you storing it.

Comment: Its my own custom precompiled framework let say myframework.framework and myframework is added relatively to myproject. But i have removed it from link target dependency as i was using other linker flag